# Error while trying to " Undo Checkout" on a Template Buildling Block

Tags: 2013-sp1

when we try to undo checkout on Template building block we get the below error,
[image]

We always see a lock on this TBB and am just not able to get rid of it.
When we go to history and try to rollback to a previous version , it says the item is checked out by me.
We did try a restart  as well.
Can someone help us with this issue...

Comment: you said you have tried a restart but, only on the Content Manager? have you restarted the database? because it seems a problem with a lock in the DB.